# Changing the color of a label every x seconds

Tags: ios, colors, label

Is there a way implement something like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCgFZ.gif I have tried using TTAttributedLabel but to no success (no flashing and time doesn't change anymore).

Does anyone know of a way to make something like this happen?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks Everyone

Matt

Comment: Show what you've tried (the closest you got) and describe what it does wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use timer.

```
- (NSTimer*)createTimer {

    // create timer on run loop
    return [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerTicked:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)timerTicked:(NSTimer*)timer {

    [yourLabel setText:@""]
    …
}

- (void)actionStop:(id)sender {

    // stop the timer
    [myTimer invalidate];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use CALayer to make it happen. Unless you make changes to the layer's default actions, every change committed on the layer in animated.
By setting up a timer you could make a repeating function that animates a change of the number to a different value (image ??) and set a completion block to change the colour.
That's what I would do.